# Possible to dynamically change the name of a symbol in a partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm curious if there's a way to change the name of a symbol in a partial based off the parameters that's passed to it.  For example, it's possible to do something like this

in a partial:

```
f.label("#{parameter}")
```

where parameter was passed into the partial when it was rendered.  Now lets say instead we have something like

```
blog_path(domestic_or_international: "domestic")
```

would it be possible to use a similar method to change the symbol `domesitc_or_international` like I did in the first example?  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the old hash syntax to do this.

```
blog_path(:"static_text_#{parameter}" => "domestic")
```